# Vue.js компонентный подход, один и тот же параметр

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Всем привет. Работаю с Vue в Laravel. Использую примерно такие компоненты:

```
Vue.component('news-create', require('./components/NewsCreate.vue').default);
Vue.component('sp-edit', require('./components/SpecEdit.vue').default);
Vue.component('sp-create', require('./components/SpecCreate.vue').default);
```

Во всех этих компонентах я использую модуль `yimo-vue-editor`. Код настройки модуля в компонентах практически одинаков:

```
import YimoVueEditor from 'yimo-vue-editor'

window.Vue.use(YimoVueEditor, {
      name: 'yimo-editor-app',
      uploadHandler: (type, resTxt) => {
        console.log(resTxt);
        if (type === 'success') {
          var res = JSON.parse(resTxt)
          if (!res) {
            return null
          }
          return res.url
        } else if (type === 'error') {
          //todo toast
        } else if (type === 'timeout') {
          //todo toast
        }
        return 'upload failed__'
      },
          uploadImgUrl: 'http://domain/upload-image/news',
          uploadHeaders: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementById('csrf-token').getAttribute('content')
          },
      }
    });
```

Единственный параметр который изменяется - это `uploadImgUrl`. Проблема состоит в том, что всегда картинка отправляется на один url `http://domain/upload-image/news`, то есть тот, который был первым подключён в `app.js`.

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое, что необходимо сделать - это глобально зарегистрировать плагин в `app.js`:

```
import VEditor from 'yimo-vue-editor'

Vue.use(VEditor, {
    name: 'yimo-vue-editor',
    config: {
        uploadImgUrl: 'http://domain/upload-image/news',
        uploadHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementById('csrf-token').getAttribute('content')
        }
    },
    uploadHandler: (type, resTxt) => {
        console.log(resTxt);
        if (type === 'success') {
            var res = JSON.parse(resTxt)
            if (!res) {
                return null
            }
            return res.url
        } else if (type === 'error') {
            //todo toast
        } else if (type === 'timeout') {
            //todo toast
        }
        return 'upload failed__'
    },

})
```

Далее при использовании в компонентах вы переопределяете свойство `config`, например:

```
<template>
<div>
  <yimo-vue-editor v-model="text" :config="myYimoConfig"></yimo-vue-editor>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
      myYimoConfig: {
        uploadImgUrl: 'http://domain/upload-image/spec',
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую Ваш способ.

Comment: Давно уже опробывал Ваш способ, всё отлично работает. Очень благодарен)